# Vert.x annotation processor problem with module-info.java

Tags: maven, netbeans, vert.x, module-info, annotation-processor

I'm trying to create a new project in Java that is composed by several modules (following the Java Modules concept introduced on Java 9). In one of those modules, I'm trying to use vert.x codegen to generate a service that will be exposed to the other modules.

Now that problem is that when I try to compile the service module I got the following error:

> module-info.java:[5,22] module not found: io.vertx.codegen.

For your reference, I will put my module configuration (as stated on module-info.java) and my POM file.

Module-info.java:

```java
module mo.com.test.daomodule {
    requires io.vertx.core;
    requires io.vertx.client.sql.mssql;
    requires io.vertx.client.sql;
    requires io.vertx.codegen;
    requires io.vertx.serviceproxy;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    
    exports mo.com.test.dao.db.service;
    exports mo.com.test.dao.db; 
}
```

My pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mo.com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>MainProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    
     <properties>
         <vertx.version>4.2.1</vertx.version>
         <jdbc.version>9.4.0.jre11</jdbc.version>
         <log4j2api.version>2.14.1</log4j2api.version>
         <log4j2core.version>2.14.1</log4j2core.version>
     </properties>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-stack-depchain</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-json-schema</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-jdbc-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-mssql-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-codegen</artifactId>  
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
            <classifier>processor</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2api.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
    
    <groupId>mo.com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>daomodule</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>daomodule</name>
</project>
```

By checking above, I have added the necessary imports in the POM file and add include the vert.x modules as required in the module-info.java.

No my question is, what can I do to solve this compilation problem? Is there anything missing on my POM or my module-info.java?

Comment: You have to change your module-info ...

Comment: @khmarbaise how should I change the module-info? More info would be appreciated to help me guide through.